# Django Rest Framework - Browsable API Form always returns 400 bad request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm having an issue where my api, which uses a very vanilla django-rest-framework setup (viewsets and model serializers) is working fine locally, and once deployed, works fine for everything but POSTing via the HTML form in the browsable API.  Any time I submit a post via this form, I get "HTTP 400 bad request".

Has anybody experienced anything similar?  I'm running NGINX/UWSGI on a centos server.

Comment: what is the value of `response.data`?

Comment: Can you give us some code? What does your serializer look like for example?

Comment: Seconding Rahul, response.data will give the reason why DRF rejected the request.

Comment: Sure.  Here is response.data:

`{
    "aggregationlevel": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "aggregationtype": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "name": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}`

Comment: And here is the serializer:

`class DataSetAPISerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DataSet`

Answer (score 1):

I had the Exact same problem as you. What worked for me was downgrading Rest framework from version 3.3.0 to version 3.2.5 . I have no idea why this worked but I hope this helps you too

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a regression. There's already a bug opened for this: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3588